# best practice to storing passwords

Tags: azure, password-manager

in order for us to store passwords(admin password of VMs, Databases, ... ) and to be able to share it in a team, we use Onenote and it's password protected but we need something that is easier to use and more resilient. I would appreciate if someone could help me finding a good solution.
we also use azure platform in case it affects finding the best solution.

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/

Comment: Do not use passwords. Use Azure AD based auth instead.

Comment: @CSharpRocks azure key vault is not easy to use. we have more than 100 passwords.  you need to pull out them from the connection string in Azure key vault

Comment: @GauravMantri but Azure AD will be roll based. sometimes we need to use the admin password of that resource.

Comment: Passwords can be leaked and shared. Most (if not all) of the resources support Azure AD based access control. It is somewhat painful to set things up but is much more secure IMO.

Comment: that's true. what about password managers? like Roboform or Keeper ?